# Memory leak declaring constants

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, instruments

Working with Instruments the other day I ran with a memory leak in a very straightforward sample code like this :

```
@IBAction func shareSheet(sender: AnyObject) {

    let firstActivityItem = "Hello there is a memory leak here..."

    let secondActivityItem : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.sample.com/")!

    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (sender as! UIButton)

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The goal of the above code is show the `UIActivityViewController` to post in social network, etc.

> **Instruments** screenshots of the **leak**:

[image]

---

[image]

Working in the problem I finally solved, changing the declaration of the two constants `firstActivityItem` and `secondActivityItem` to variables the memory leak is gone.

But my question here is why is that?

Why generate a memory leak with `let` and not with `var` declaration?

Comment: @nhgrif But why Instrument detect it as a leak then? How I manage this then ?

Comment: The string is created at compile-time and put in the data segment , a copy should never need to be made for a constant reference.

Comment: FileUrlwithpath it is not for weblinks. It is only for local resource files. For links you have to use NSURL(string:)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Yes you're right, my mistake, updated question

Answer (score 0):

Best bet, it is a Swift issue that may be resolved in an update.

The string is created at compile-time and put in the data segment, a copy should never need to be made for a constant reference.

Please submit a bug report: http://bugreport.apple.com